# How to remove picker from column header of Ext JS Grid

Tags: extjs, grid, styles

I want to remove the picker (that has options for sorting and column selection) from the column header of a grid. I'm using Ext JS 4.1.1

[image]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In Ext3, that would be done by specifying `menuDisabled: true` in the column definition. Not sure about Ext4, though.

Comment: I am using ExtJs 4. It is not working in that. Is there any alternative solution?

Comment: I use ExtJs 4.2.2 and have no problem there. Documentation [here](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Column-cfg-menuDisabled)

Comment: Also works for 5.1. http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Column-cfg-menuDisabled

Comment: I logged in just to up your answer :), exactly what I needed. Thought this is a sort button, turned out it's menu button.

Answer (score 9):

This has moved around over the years.

In 4.2.2 (current in May 2014) there is a property that can be set for each column:

```
menuDisabled:true

sortable:false // menu shows but no sort options

hideable:false // menu shows but column name not shown in columns menu

menuDisabled:true // no menu
```

Those are for individual columns. For the grid header as a whole see also http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.grid.header.Container-cfg-enableColumnHide

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful. Works for ExtJS 5 as well. I have filtering and menuDisabled:true removed the filtering as well, but hideable: true worked fine.